# How to find elements in a list by last two elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list `list= {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3},......}` in which I want to find the element "an" by giving the values of {bn, cn} in the same order.

For example, if

`list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 6, 5}}`

For {5, 6}, I should get 4, not 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 6, 5}};
asso = GroupBy[list, Rest -> First];
asso[{5, 6}]
(* {4} *)
```

If any $\{b_n, c_n\}$ occurs at most once, it's not necessary to have a list returned:

```
asso = GroupBy[list, Rest -> First, First];
asso[{5, 6}]
(* 4 *)
```

Answer (score 8):

A simplified version of @kglr's function:

```
f[b_, c_] := Cases[list, {a_, b, c} -> a]

f[5, 6]
(*    {4}    *)
```

If you are sure that there is only one matching case, you can gain some speed by replacing [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) with [`FirstCase`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstCase.html):

```
g[b_, c_] := FirstCase[list, {a_, b, c} -> a]

g[5, 6]
(*    4    *)
```

Comment: I think I like this better than Coolwater's solution.

Comment: @J.M. it depends on the use case. If many pairs are to be looked up in the same `list`, then @Coolwater's one-time pre-grouping is the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
list//Pick[#[[All,1]],#[[All,2;;]], {5,6}]&
```

> {4}

Comment: Or `list//Extract[#[[All,1]],Position[#[[All,2;;]], {5,6}]]&`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 6, 5}};
```

Using `Extract`

```
p = Append[1] /@ Position[list, {__, 5, 6}]
```

{{2, 1}}

```
Extract[list, p]
```

{4}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 6, 5}};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {_, 5, 6}} :> First@s]

(*{4}*)
```